# Sticky element to top on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my div appear at the top when the user scrolls down the page, and once the user scrolls to the top, the element should not overlap the nav bar.

I am struggling to implement this, so help would be appreciated. This is what I have tried:

```
 <div id="floating-sidebar-sticky-wrapper" class="floating-sidebar-wrap" style="height: 696px;">
 <div id="floating-sidebar"></div>
</div>


 <script>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
      $("#floating-sidebar").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, wrapperClassName: "floating-sidebar-wrap" });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any javascript or even jquery to do that.

Try the [Sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) CSS position

```css
.top-nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2em;
}
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 2em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">Top nav</div>
<div class="">
<h2>Sticky Element: Scroll Down to See the Effect</h2>
<p>Scroll down this page to see how  sticky positioning works.</p>
<div class="sticky">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>

<p>Some example text..</p>
<h2>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.</p>
<div class="sticky" style="background:red">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>
<h2>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.</p>
<h2>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give it a try:
it doesn't use jquery or javascript.

```css
.content-section {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
.sidebar-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.sidebar-item {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 /* Position the items */
 // &:nth-child(2) { top: 25%; }
 // &:nth-child(3) { top: 50%; }
 // &:nth-child(4) { top: 75%; }
}


.make-me-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
    
  padding: 0 15px;
}



/* Ignore This, just coloring */
body {
  background: #fff;
}

article {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 25px 0 600px;
}


.title-section, .content-section, .sidebar-section {
  background: #fff;
  // border-radius: 12px;
  // border: solid 10px #f1f1f1; 
}

.title-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content-section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.sidebar-item {
  text-align: center;
  
  h3 {
    background: gold;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0 100px; 
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
   <div class="title-section">
        <h1>Your Navigation Bar</h1>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-7">

   <div class="content-section">
        <h2>Your Body Content Section</h2>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-5">

   <div class="sidebar-item">
   <div class="make-me-sticky">
        <h3>Your Sidebar</h3>
   </div>
   </div>
          

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

[source:codepen](https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/eKNROb)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Chrome. Provide the top value as your Nav bar height so it will be always below the Nav bar when user will scroll up to the top.

```
position: sticky;
top: 100px;---Replace 100 with your Nav bar height
z-index: 99;
```